# How to access a specific object in serialized data?

Tags: java, flatbuffers

I'm using FlatBuffers to serialize a graph for an Android app I'm building (so I don't have to re-build it each time the user opens the app), but I'm having a bit of an issue with the deserialization process.

The graph is represented by a `List<Vertex>` and here is the important snippet of the `Vertex` class:

```
public final class Vertex {
    private final List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
    private int lbl;
    private float lat;
    private float lon;
    private int actualCostFromSource;
    private int numInitialized;
    private int pqKey;
    private int predecessorLabel = -1;
}
```

The `Edge` class is also quite simple:

```
public final class Edge {
    private final int endVertexLabel;
    private short length;
    private short travelTime;
}
```

Now, I can serialize and deserialize the complete graph with almost no issues (well, I do have one, but that's for another question). However, when I chose to go with FlatBuffers in the first place, I was under the assumption that I would be able to retrieve a vertex from the serialized data without having to deserialize it completely.

For each vertex I serialized, I saved its offset (the `int` the corresponding `create...` method returns) in the serialized data in a text file, so I know that e.g., the zero-th vertex starts at position 68 and, while the first at 144. Can’t I do something like the following the get the former?

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(144 - 68);
// Create an InputStream using the serialized BIN file.
inputStream.getChannel().read(buffer, 68);
Vertex v = Vertex.getRootAsVertex(buffer);
```

From what I gather from the documentation, this is valid, but the `ByteBuffer` always throws an `IndexOutOfBoundException` like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:749)
    at java.base/java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.getInt(DirectByteBuffer.java:692)
    at com.dimitrismantas.torch.util.serial.Vertex.getRootAsVertex(Vertex.java:42)
    at com.dimitrismantas.torch.util.serial.Vertex.getRootAsVertex(Vertex.java:36)
    at com.dimitrismantas.torch.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

Is what I’m attempting to do even possible? And if so, how do I do it?

Thanks.

P.S: I’ve also noticed that, while my graph has `X` vertices, the file containing their offsets has less than `X` entries. What’s up with that?

Comment: Don't save the offsets externally (in a text file!), only use them construct new data structures internally (like a vector of those offsets) in the FlatBuffer. Those offsets also are from the end of the buffer, so that is where your code may go wrong, but really, you shouldn't be using them directly at all.

Comment: Hi, @Aardappel. Thanks for answering.


Each vertex has a different out-degree (so a different size) and that's why I need to look up its offset. How else could I access a single one without using its offset? I think the idea of a file is indeed a bit insecure, so that's probably why you don't approve of it. Maybe a serialized data structure would be a better bet.

Comment: Your problem is coming from here (check same for the JDK version you are usinf, they probably willbe the same): https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/nio/Buffer.java#L530 Check the limits of the buffer (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#limit()) and try setting it to the capacity.

Comment: @DimitrisMantas FlatBuffers itself already deals fine with differing sizes of serialized objects. Just serialize a root object with a vector of Vertex. Read the docs.

Comment: @Aardappel please excuse my ignorance, but if I have serialized a `List<Object>` and want to access the `Object` at *original* index `i`, without deserializing the whole `List`, how should I proceed given a BIN file of the whole thing? The documentation explains how to serialize only one object, so I believe my use case is not explained there. I believe I need to prefix the object size to the buffer using `finish(root, true)`, but I'm lost after that...

Comment: For anyone else having a similar question, you need to map the serialized file channel to memory using `MappedByteBuffer`, and then pass that to the `getRootas..` method. That’s it, you can then have random access to your data. Also, check out this post for reference:https://groups.google.com/g/flatbuffers/c/b8SlYTdDp-U. Definitely not the documentation that helped me figure this out…